p:commandLink in facet inside a form causing warning log that it's not inside a form
I created a composite component that renders a form and an ul like this:
<h:form id="formid">
   <ul>
       <composite:renderFacet name="listItems" />
   </ul>
</h:form>

I am using the facet like this:
<my:comp id="componentId"
    <f:facet name="listItems">
        <li>
            <p:commandLink id="import-button" title="#{msg['import.title']}">
            ....

But using this I get a warning in the log:

Component 'componentId:import-button' should be inside a form or should reference a form via its form attribute. We will try to find a fallback form on the client side.

I am not expecting this error because the facet is inside a form?! Also when I inspect the code in the browser it is inside the form.
Am I missing something here?
Update:
PF Version 12.0.7
h:commandLink seems to work, but I need the PF functionalities in this case

Did you try with 14.0.2 or a different Faces implementation? If the issue persists, please create an issue.

I tried with 13.0.10. same issue

its just a warning, ignore it
otherwise feel free to create a PR on primefaces for better detection. Currently we just loop all parents to find the form and with tags/includes/templating it doesnt work as exepcted as you can see.

Yep this warning was trying to give people a hint when they didn't have it inside a form but with Composite Components our logic to detect if its in a form is clearly not working :)

Adding form="formid" to the commandlink seems to eliminate the warning.
